# VS Code- Angular Essentials extension causes errors

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code. I just downloaded the extension called 'Angular Essentials' and after Installing it I get a few code errors. I will put a picture to explain:

[image]

Now when I do "ng serve" everything runs and working, but still all this red lines are annoying. 
Another issue is that even if I change the (") to (') when I save the file all the (') turns automatically to ("). how can I get rid of that?

Comment: That extension tells prettier to prefer single quotes, evidently you have something else that conflicts with that.

Comment: how can I change it?

Comment: I don't know what other extensions and settings you have, so it's pretty well impossible to answer more specifically. Overriding the prettier setting to prefer *double* quotes should help with that specific issue, but there may be other conflicts.

Comment: I have no other extensions... I just downloaded vs code and then the angular essentials. what cause ' change automatically to " when I hit save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"prettier.singleQuote": true

fixed the problem